# how download a site for a specific format with wget

Tags: downloads, wget

How can download all urls to follow a format like as `www.site.com/fooXXX`
when XXX could be any number between 0-999, its posible?

Comment: Does this http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114660/download-multiple-urls-at-once answer your question?

Comment: Of course you can, you got some error? what have you tried?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply use Bash's range syntax to specify the URL:

```
wget 'http://www.example.com/foo'{0..999}
```

This would be equal to the command written out like this (leaving most of the URLs in between out, because I'm too lazy to type 1000 URLs):

```
wget 'http://www.example.com/foo0' 'http://www.example.com/foo1' ... 'http://www.example.com/foo42' ... 'http://www.example.com/foo999'
```

Comment: If you need leading zeros: `printf "http://www.example.com/foo%03d\n" {0..999} | xargs wget`

Comment: @ScottDeagan or simply `wget 'http://www.example.com/foo'{0..9}{0..9}{0..9}`

Comment: That's awesome! I've learnt something new today - thanks.